# Is there an optical/electromagnetic equivalent to the mechanical lever?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, radio-frequency

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lever): "Levers can be used to exert a large force over a small distance at one end by exerting only a small force (effort) over a greater distance at the other."

Is there any material that can do something similar for light/electromagnetic radiation with respect to their wavelength/frequency?

For example, at one end I input light and at the output I get radio waves.

The frequency of the input is reduced. But by the lever analogy, something else should increase. Would this be the wavelength?

I can imagine using a solar cell to power a radio transmitter, but this does not follow the analogy of the lever and isn't efficient.

Can you explain simply if this is possible or not? I am not smart.

Answer (score 0):

In short, Levers amplify the forces by repositioning the center of gravity.

There are many components that do same in photonics/optics/electromagnetism

**Amplifier**: Amplifies the optical power, used in optical fiber communication to improve SNR (reduce the noise) and transmit the signal over large distances

**Nonlinear optical components:** shifts the wavelength/frequency of input signal to different wavelength/frequency.

**Polarizers/wave-plates**: changes the polarization of light (optical EM waves).

**Radio Over fiber**:  converts the optical frequencies to radio and vice versa for a specific transmission application.

Solar cell usually correspond to generated power and Radio transmitter usually corresponds to signal transmission at specific frequencies.

I recommend you to study the basic analogies like power, electromagnetic spectrum, frequency, wavelength.